# How to simplify generation of number range using linq?

Tags: linq

If I have a number `x` which can change, say its now `25`... how do I do the below in a simpler way?

```
colQty.DataSource = new List<Int16> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
 var range = Enumerable.Range(start: 1, count: x).ToList();
```

And you could use `ToList<Int16>()` but I wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 25);
```

This will create an `IEnumerable<int>` with the numbers 1 to 25. If you need a `List<int>` instead, add `.ToList()` after `Range`:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 25).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<int>();

for(var i = 1; i <= x; i++){ list.Add(i);}

colQty.DataSource = list;
```